# PySark: combine two dataframes where one is repeated for all distinct rows from the other

Tags: pyspark, concatenation

I have two pyspark dataframes where they look like the following:

df1:

```
Col1   Col2
1      A
2      B
```

and df2:

```
Col3   Col4
100    200
300    400
```

My desired outcome of the combining operations would be:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
1       A       100     200
1       A       300     400
2       B       100     200
2       B       300     400
```

There are no shared columns between the two dataframes which is what makes this tricky and I couldn't find anything that would do this so any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `crossJoin` method.

PS: This is an **expensive** operation and should be avoided if possible.

```
df = df1.crossJoin(df2)
df.show()
```